# Adding CMake Includes to the List so it appears in Xocde Project Navigator

Tags: xcode, cmake

When CMake is used to generate an Xcode project, the CMakeLists.txt file is included in the Project Navigator window so it is easy to click on and edit. I have written a CMake file that includes some utility functions in CMakeUtils.txt and is then included with `INCLUDE(../CMakeUtils.txt)`. How can I make this file appear below the main cmake file in the Project Navigator?

If I add this file as a RESOURCE it will be included with the executable, and that's not right. How do I add a compile-time resource to be listed in Project Navigator but not included with the code?

[image]

For example, the following CMakeLists.txt file would contain the cmake file but not its includes. The associated test.cpp and CMakeUtils.txt files can be empty:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeUtils.txt)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 3.17.2)

PROJECT(demo_include)
ADD_LIBRARY(test test.cpp)
```

Comment: It looks like just adding it the the library/executable list might work `ADD_LIBRARY(test test.cpp CMakeUtils.txt)` but it's unclear how a `txt` file is treated differently than a `cpp` or `h` file

Comment: In Visual Studio it would just be a text file and the IDE knows it is not source code. Also take a look at `source_group()` on how to organize your files.

Comment: Typically, these CMake utility files have the suffix `.cmake`, not sure if that will allow XCode to see it more easily.